# jQuery AJAX loop result

Tags: jquery

I have a question about the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'ajax.php',
        'data': ({todo: "fetch"}),
        'success': function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#result').html(value.name);
            });
        }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

The result div is showing only the last data. How can I Summary all data into the result div?
I tried

```
var i = 0;
```

and in the loop i++; but this does not work.

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please try this $('#result').html($('#result').html() + value.name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because on every loop, you are replacing the value of `#result` in the process of `$('#result').html(value.name);` Try to append it instead. `$('#result').append('data here')`

Comment: Sure. Just press the arrow up for this to be voted up for the other that will encounter this issue. Thank you :)